# c++ characters to numbers both capital and lower characters

Tags: c++, char, int

I'm setting up a program of battleship in c++ where i have encountered a puzzle of designatting coordinates to board. I want to use both capital and lower characters designated to specific areas of the board. F.exs A2, H4, or a2, h4 etc. I have tried to implement this outside the main code for propper check and for debugging.

```
std::char c;
int x=0;
std::cout<<"Test letters to numbers using char(): "; std::cin>>c;
x=char(c);
if(x>=65||x<97){//should i do && or ||? //If statement works in Capital letters A is 0 etc.
    x=x-65;   
}if(x>=97){//does not work
    x=x-97;
}

std::cout<<"letter: "<<c<<"\tNumber: "<<x<<endl;
```

This code works in the capital letters. But not towards lower case which shows a= 32.

There are no bugs that shows when running this code. Any tips?

Comment: Why not just include `<cctype>` and convert everything `tolower()` first? Then you can ignore what case the user inputs information in. (also, don't use *magic-numbers*, use `'a'` when you mean `'a'` and `'A'` when you mean `'A'` instead of `97` and `65`)

Comment: will try using <cctype>

Comment: ok , that works, Thanks, should i share the results?

Comment: The character set used in strings is implementation-defined, and the notions of upper or lower case depend on system localisation settings (e.g. the set of lower/upper case letters for a user in Russia will differ from those in the U.K.).   You are assuming an ASCII (or compatible) character set, which is not guaranteed.    Instead, use `<cctype>` functions like `islower()` and `isupper()`  (to detect upper or lower case) or `tolower()` and `toupper()` to change case of letters.

Comment: @Peter I think it's actually ANSI not ASCII, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @nada - ANSI is the name of a standards institute.   ASCII is the common name of one character set (American Standard Code for Information Interchange)

Comment: @Peter Oh okay, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

```
    char c;
    int x=0;
    std::cout<<"Test letters to numbers using char(): "; std::cin>>c;
    x=tolower(char(c));//include cctype
    if(x>=97)
    {
        x=x-97;
    }
    std::cout<<"letter: "<<c<<"\tNumber: "<<x<<endl;
```